# Get number after keyword in string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a string in a file of the format

```
opt1= abc  opt2= 3 opt3= 10 opt4= 0
```

Now I want to read out the number after the `opt3` for example.

I would first start with grepping for the line

```
grep opt3 file |
```

and pipe it to the next command. But now I don't really know how to proceed, my shell skills are pretty rudimentary..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With grep and Perl-compatible regexes (PCRE):

```
grep -Po 'opt3=\s*\K\d+'
```

- The `-o` option makes `grep` only print matching text
- `\K` in PCRE indicates that the match actually starts from here: the preceding expression should be tested for, but not included in the matching text
- `opt3=\s*` is `opt3` followed by spaces, which is not included in the matching text, hence only the number after is printed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `cut` command to do same:

```
cut -d' ' -f7 file
```

Information:

`-d`: delimiter (what separates the fields)

`-f7`: print the seventh field

Comment: What if it wasn't 7th filed ? :D

Comment: Then another method will be used :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
grep -Po "(?<=opt3=\s)[0-9]+" file
```

- `(?<=opt3=\s)`: we are looking for "opt3= " however we are not going to include it.
- `0-9]+` the number after "opt3="
- `-o` only show the match