# How to grep only certain word in 1 line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am checking the password complexity of `ocredit` in `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` which is this line :

```
password   requisite pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=1 gecoscheck=1
```

I would like to grep the ocredit value "1" and make it as variable, let say `check_ocredit`.

My script would be checking, if the ocredit value is not 0, then it will return "true", otherwise, it will show what is the current value set in `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`.

Here's my logic that I'm going to implement :

```
if [[ $check_ocredit -ne "0" ]]
then
   true
else
   echo "Current ocredit value is : $check_ocredit"
fi
```

The output will looks like this :

```
Current ocredit value is : 1
```

I try with :

```
grep ocredit /etc/pam.d/password-auth | awk '{print $10}' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

But I was thinking, what if ocredit is missing, or it is not at 10th position.. so my result would be wrong. Can anyone advice me on this?

Comment: I just figure a way to get the ocredit value is by running this :

grep ocredit /etc/pam.d/password-auth | sed -n 's/^.*ocredit/ocredit/p' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'

but, I am open if anyone have other simpler method to share. Thank you.

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/922615/158442

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in a single `grep` command with `-o` for "print only the matching portion of the line" and `-P` which gives us `\K`: "ignore anything matched up to here":

```
$ grep -oP 'ocredit=\K\d+' /etc/pam.d/password-auth
1
```

So, in your script, you could do:

```
check_ocredit=$(grep -oP 'ocredit=\K\d+' /etc/pam.d/password-auth)
if [[ "$check_ocredit" -ne "0" ]]
then
     echo "Current ocredit value is : $check_ocredit"
fi
```

Your version of the `if` would have printed the value only when it was 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
awk -F'(ocredit=)' '{print $2}' /etc/pam.d/password-auth | awk '{print $1}'
```

To get the value in variable possible solution can be:

```
check_ocredit=$(awk -F'(ocredit=)' '{print $2}' /etc/pam.d/password-auth | awk '{print $1}')
```

The first `awk` will get the substring after `ocredit=` which will be something like `1 gecoscheck=1`  in your case, and the second `awk` will get you only the number.

Comment: It probably can be done in a single `awk` call like `awk -F'ocredit=' '{print substr($2,1,1)}'`

Answer (score 1):

If `sed` is an option, then:

```
sed -n 's/.*ocredit=\([0-1]\).*/\1/p' /etc/pam.d/password-auth
```

Will look **only**(*to match any single number, use `[0-9]` instead of `[0-1]`*) for either a `0` or a `1` after `ocredit=` and print it if found ... The output of that `sed` command can be stored in a variable e.g. `check_ocredit` using command substitution syntax like so:

```
check_ocredit=$(sed -n 's/.*ocredit=\([0-1]\).*/\1/p' /etc/pam.d/password-auth)
```

It can be evaluated in your script in a more compact way(*yielding similar result as you intend in your example*) like so:

```bash
check_ocredit=$(sed -n 's/.*ocredit=\([0-1]\).*/\1/p' /etc/pam.d/password-auth)
[ "$check_ocredit" -eq "0" ] && echo "It's a zero" || echo "It's a $check_ocredit"
```